# CSS button edge in IE9

Tags: css, button, internet-explorer-9

I've been trying to create button for my website. It works fine in everything but IE9, where I have black edges in the corners of the box. I used F12 to find which part of a code messes up everything and it appears that "filter:progid..." is the reason for that, but then again, it looks even worse without it. I read countless sites but didn't find any solution. If someone has an idea how to fix - please help! :)

[Mozilla vs IE](http://s10.postimg.org/x7tu26a6d/Mozilla_vs_IE.jpg) - image of what's going on. Mozilla on top, IE bottom.

```
.button {font: bold;
background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #000000), color-stop(1, #000000));
background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #000000 5%, #000000 100%);
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000000 5%, #000000 100%);
background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #000000 5%, #000000 100%);
background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #000000 5%, #000000 100%);
background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #000000 5%, #000000 100%);
overflow:auto;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000000',     endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0);
-moz-border-radius:42px;
-webkit-border-radius:42px;
border-radius:42px;
color: #BDBDBD;
padding:3px 55px;
width: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer is unfortunately known having issues when it comes to gradients.

That being said this is something that has been addressed in another posts which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399726/ie9-filter-gradient-and-border-radius-conflict) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685254/css3-gradient-problem-in-ie) which uses a svg gradient to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to fix with SVG.